# Gridview BackGround Color changing Color when Scrolling in Android

Tags: java, android, gridview, background-color

`GridView` item color changes randomly whenever I scroll.

Every item color is based on the status of the SQLite database, but when I tried to scroll multiple times it change the color of the item randomly. Is there any way to solve this? This is what it looks like.

[image: 1stScroll-Image]

[image: 2ndScroll-Image]

Here is the code

**GetView**

```
private class ViewHolder{
    ImageView imageView, mPreviewCashCard;
    TextView txtName, txtPrice, txtSeriesNo;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    Cursor cursor = MainActivity.sqLiteHelper.getData("SELECT id,status FROM DarkMode");
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        DarkModeStatus = cursor.getString(1);
    }

    View row = view;
    ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();

    if(row == null){
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        row = inflater.inflate(layout, null);
        holder.txtName = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txtName);
        holder.txtPrice = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txtPrice);
        holder.txtSeriesNo = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txtSeriesNumber);
        holder.imageView = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imgFood);
        holder.mPreviewCashCard = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imgId);
        row.setTag(holder);
    }
    else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
    }
    Inventory inventory = inventoryList.get(position);
    holder.txtName.setText(inventory.getName());
    holder.txtPrice.setText(inventory.getPrice());
    holder.txtSeriesNo.setText(inventory.getSeriesNumber());
    int status = inventory.getStatus();
    if (status==0 && DarkModeStatus.matches("false")){
        row.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FEF8DD"));
    }
    else if(status==0 && DarkModeStatus.matches("true")){
        row.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#282828"));
    }

    byte[] CashCardImage = inventory.getImage();
    byte[] idImage = inventory.getIdImage();
    if(CashCardImage.length > 1)
    {
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(CashCardImage, 0, CashCardImage.length);
        holder.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }
    else{
        holder.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_image);
    }
    if(idImage.length > 1)
    {
        Bitmap bitmap2 = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(idImage, 0, idImage.length);
        holder.mPreviewCashCard.setImageBitmap(bitmap2);
    }
    else{
        holder.mPreviewCashCard.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_image);
    }
    return row;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding an else condition to your if-else block handling backgrounds.

```
     if (status==0 && DarkModeStatus.matches("false")){
        row.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FEF8DD"));
    }
    else if(status==0 && DarkModeStatus.matches("true")){
        row.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#282828"));
    }else {
        row.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF")); // white or whichever default background color you are using
    }
```

From my understanding this could fix the issue.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I tried that before but I can't do that because I used  `Darkmode` on my app, the else statement is based on the app color since that is the static way  I just leave that else statement as a background default in my XML. But even so, I did use that, I think the result will the same, do you have any idea? I'm just stuck with this module :(

Comment: Since the condition is also based on Dark mode, Can't you create a color resource in values for white and dark theme and link it here? In that case you don't need to manually check for dark theme enabled or not. Refer this for more details https://proandroiddev.com/implementing-dark-theme-in-your-android-application-ec2b4fefb6e3

Comment: Thanks it works now! I just add some conditions based on the DarkMode